# Two DataTables sourced from different APIs on the same page show the same data

Tags: javascript, datatables

I have two DataTables on the same web page with the same number of columns that are sourced from DIFFERENT APIs. If I add the class "grid" to one or the other the table displays with the correct data for that table. However, if I add the class "grid" to both, the data for the first table shows up on BOTH tables.

The class "grid" is a very complex DataTable that involves quite a bit of configuration but here is how "grid" is initialized:

```
var t = $(".grid").DataTable({
        iDisplayLength: 10,
        columnDefs: [{
            "searchable": false,
            "orderable": bOrderBy,
            "targets": 0
        }],
        order: [[0, orderDir]],
        ajax: {
            url: src,
            dataSrc: ""
        },
        columns: [
            {
                data: f1
            },
            {
                data: f2
            },
            {
                data: f3
            },
            {
                data: f4
            },
            {
                data: f5,
. . . "blah, blah, blah"
});

t.on('post-body.bs.table', function () {
        $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({
            container: 'body',
            placement: 'top'
        });
    });


    if (autoNum == "Y") {
        t.on('order.dt search.dt', function () {
            t.column(0, { search: 'applied', order: 'applied' }).nodes().each(function (cell, i) {
                cell.innerHTML = i + 1;
            });
        }).draw();
    }
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Right now, it is applying the same DataTable instance to anything selected in your .grid selector which is why they are coming back the same.  If the table options are the same, you can save this into a obj and then pass it to each call.  Name the 2 tables with different id's or different classes

```
var dtOptions = {
    iDisplayLength: 10,
    columnDefs: [{
        "searchable": false,
        "orderable": bOrderBy,
        "targets": 0
    }],
    order: [[0, orderDir]],
    ajax: {
        url: src,
        dataSrc: ""
    },
    columns: [
        {
            data: f1
        },
        {
            data: f2
        },
        {
            data: f3
        },
        {
            data: f4
        },
        {
            data: f5,
. . . "blah, blah, blah"
};

$("#mytable1).DataTable(dtOptions);
$("#mytable2).DataTable(dtOptions);
```

You may need to change the ajax src for the 2nd table as you said they are coming from separate api's.  You could possibly copy the options object and modify the ajax src if needed.

```
var dtOptions2= $.extend(true, {}, dtOptions);
dtOptions2.ajax.url = "somthing-else...";
$("#mytable2).DataTable(dtOptions2);
```

Comment: Thank you, Paul, for your answer. This won't work because that would require creating separate options for each table (I plan to have at least 5 tables on the same page inside a bootstrap accordion component). The options are coming from specific data attributes I created in the tables themselves. This keeps me from having to "re-create the wheel" so to speak for each table.

Comment: There are many table attributes but the most relevant are these containing the json field data: let f1 = $(".grid").attr("data-f1");
    let f2 = $(".grid").attr("data-f2");
    let f3 = $(".grid").attr("data-f3");
    let f4 = $(".grid").attr("data-f4");
    let f5 = $(".grid").attr("data-f5");

Comment: Have a look at using your current setup but specifying a function for the ajax: property https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax  This function has the DataTable settings object passed in which should contain a reference to the table the function is being run on.  You could do something in there to determine the correct ajax call (src) that should go out for that table.

Comment: Oh yes, I remember way back when about this: "ajax": function (data, callback, settings) {
    callback(
      JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem('dataTablesData') )
    ); but never found a concrete example of how to make it work. In this example it uses the "local storage" (SERIOUSLY PEOPLE???) instead of an API. Placing the API source directly does not work.